# When querying InfluxDB with curl, how to handle unicode characters?

Tags: shell, curl, unicode, influxdb

I would like to delete all the collectd monitoring data for an invalid host. I believe I should delete all the series tagged with that host.

Before dropping the series I would like to see them. I run queries using curl, I tried the following.

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8086/query' --data-urlencode "db=collectd_db" --data-urlencode "q=SHOW SERIES WHERE host='<HOST>'"
```

It does work for valid hosts, e.g.: `host.example.com`. I see some JSON output which at first sight is consistent with my expectations.

However the host I would like to delete the data for is called `"C(\u0000\u0008\u0000\u000c\u0016MlT\ufffd/\ufffdh\u0000\u0005\u0000\tnice\u0000\u0000\u0006\u0000"`. I obtained this value running the following query: `SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY=host`.

Below are a few ways that don't work.

```
$ HOST='...' # Value as above, cannot copy-paste due to formatting bugs.

$ curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8086/query' --data-urlencode "db=collectd_db" --data-urlencode "q=SHOW SERIES WHERE host='`echo -e $HOST`'"
{"results":[{}]}

$ HOST='...' # Value as above with double backslashes, cannot copy-paste due to formatting bugs.

$ curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8086/query' --data-urlencode "db=collectd_db" --data-urlencode "q=SHOW SERIES WHERE host='$HOST'"
{"results":[{}]}
```

Any idea?

Comment: I have resolved my problem, but not answered my question. For the record the solution was to issue a query which selects all the series except those with a valid host. e.g.: `SHOW SERIES WHERE host!='abc.example.com' and host!='efg.example.com' AND`...

Comment: If you found the answer, add it as answer and accept it.

Comment: I found out a workaround, but not the answer to the question.